# Error when using OUTPUT parameter with sp_execute

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm having a problem with dynamic SQL and reduced my code to this simplest possible example. Why does this:

```
DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(1000), @Name SYSNAME;
SET @Statement = N'SELECT TOP 1 @Name = name from sys.objects';
EXEC sp_execute @Statement, N'@Name SYSNAME OUTPUT', @Name OUTPUT;
```

Get me this:

```
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_execute, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@handle' of type 'int'.
```

What is the correct syntax?

I also tried:

```
DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(1000), @Name SYSNAME;
SET @Statement = N'SELECT TOP 1 @NameOUT = name from sys.objects';
EXEC sp_execute @Statement, N'@NameOUT SYSNAME OUTPUT', @NameOUT = @Name OUTPUT;
```

But had the same errror.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you meant to use `sp_executesql` instead, since you're executing a SQL string. Compare the documentation: [sp_execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848746.aspx) vs. [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Comment: i always use **sp_execute** at first as well